# How to display an email on a TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, email, rendering

I'm using an IdImap4 + Idmessage to receive emails.

But I couldn't find out:

1. how to display a received HTML formatted email body on a TWebBrowser?
2. wether it is possible to show the simple text messages on a TWebBrowser, too? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible to display an email's HTML, however `TWebBrowser` is not really well-suited for this purpose.  You need to store the HTML in memory that is accessible via an `IStream` interface (such as by using the `TMemoryStream` and `TStreamAdapter` classes), then navigate the browser to the `"about:blank"` URL via the `TWebBrowser::Navigate2()` method and wait for the `TWebBrowser::OnDocumentComplete` event to fire, then query the document for its `IPersistStreamInit` interface and pass the `IStream` to the `IPersistStreamInit::Load()` method.

There are subtle quirks with displaying in-memory HTML in general, let alone displaying HTML from an email.  In particular, the email's HTML may have dependancies on images and other resources that are located elsewhere in the email, which cannot be loaded in `TWebBrowser` without saving them to temp files and altering the HTML to refer to them.  You are better off using a third-party HTML viewer, such as the HTML viewing components from [http://www.pbear.com](http://www.pear.com), that support manually providing the data for requested resources.  Then you can pull the data from the `TIdMessage` as needed.

To display other messages in the browser, you will likely have to manipulate the document's DOM after the initial page is loaded (unless you alter the HTML inline before displaying it).

Comment: unfortunately Pbear htmlviewer doesn't support Delphi Xe . do you know any other third-party html viewer ?

Comment: I found the updatd version of this HTml Viewer . thank you very much for your help .

Answer (score -1):

Save your email as "email.mhtml" and then load on TWebBrowser.
use Navigate method to load.

After that the browser will do all you want.
Will read the text as simple text when he exist, but priority will be for the HTML body.

I realy sorry to correct the Remy Lebeau answer, but at this time I am right and he is wrong.
I say that with tears in my eyes...
Gambit